# Emacs: Dired the files under the current directory whose name matches a regular expression?

Tags: regex, search, recursion, emacs, dired

I want something like `find-name-dired`, but with a regular expression instead of a shell wildcard.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you ask if you use [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus).

1. First, use **`M-+ M-i`**, to insert all of the subdirectories ***here and below*** into the current Dired buffer - that is, all directories under the current Dired directory.
2. Next, use **`% m`**, to mark all files and directories whose names match a regexp you enter.
3. Next, use **`C-M-*`**, to open Dired on just the files and directories that are marked.

You can also do this another way using **Dired+**, without bothering to insert descendant subdir directories into the ancestor Dired buffer:

1. Use **`M-- M-+ % m`** to mark all files ***here and below*** that match the regexp.
2. Use **`M-- M-+ F`** to open all of the marked files ***here and below***.

Prefix key **`M-+`** has "here-and-below" keys/commands that are similar to commands that act only on the files listed in the current Dired buffer.  The commands are essentially the same as those without the prefix key: `M-+ % m` is the "deep" version of `% m`, `M-+ F` is the "deep" version of `F`, and so on.

(The negative prefix arg (`M--`) tells these commands to ignore any markings of subdirectories themselves, in this Dired buffer and any Dired buffers for descendant directories.)